# How to get total children count of all childs available in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase Realtime Database structure is:

```
{
"Declare":{
  "GokulAsGokul1":{
     "10-2020":{"Month":"10-2020"},
     "5-2021":{"Month":"5-2021"},
     "5-2023":{"Month":"5-2023"},
     "5-2026":{"Month":"5-2026"},
     "5-2027":{"Month":"5-2027"}
  },
  "GokulAsGokul2":{
     "10-2025":{"Month":"10-2025"},
     "5-2021":{"Month":"5-2021"}
  },
  "GokulAsGokul3":{
     "6-2021":{"Month":"6-2021"}
  },
  "GokulAsGokul4":{
     "4-2021":{ "Month":"4-2021"}
  }
 }
}
```

Each user has some set of data like GokulAsGokul1 has 5 sets and GokulAsGokul2 has 2 sets. And I want all user's sets of data count. It would be 5+2+1+1=9. But I got the result as 4 only.

My code is:

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Declare");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String name = Long.toString(snapshot.getChildrenCount());
            Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you should get one level deeper in your database, by looping over the "DataSnapshot" object twice. So the following lines of code will do the trick:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference declareRef = rootRef.child("Declare");
declareRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            int count = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot nameSnapshot : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot dateSnapshot : nameSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "count: " + count);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
count: 9
```

With your code, you get only 4, because you are looping online over the children of "Declare" node, which are 4. GokulAsGokul1, GokulAsGokul2, GokulAsGokul3 and GokulAsGokul4.